# Eclipse - Hover not showing variables in abstract Java class

Tags: java, eclipse, hover, abstract-class, spring-tool-suite

I'm currently using Spring Tool Suite 2.9.2 (based off of Eclipse 3.x).

In every class that I debug through, it has no issue with on-hover displaying the values of my variables.  But, when I am in an abstract class, on-hover just displays the variable type and name.

This is super frustrating to me, because the values get displayed in the Variables window.  I usually go "Oh, I'm in an abstract class..." and I have to switch my perspective.

**Is there anyway that I can display values on-hover in an abstract class with Eclipse?**

I've tried resetting hover options to default and checking the combined hover button to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

You can select the variable  and do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to inspect/view the value of that variable.

Comment: Awesome!  I'm going to have to start using that.  Is there anyway to have this be the default behavior though?